# Parsing JSON in Android; arrayList_ph is null

Tags: android, json

Please help me to parse the following JSON data given below:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      count: 1,
      user_id: "1",
      name: "Dave Greeneberg",
      email: "daveneberg@example.com",
      profile_photo: "http://phontest.lbch.com//users/user1.jpg",
      contest_count: "3",
      photo_count: 19,
      win_count: "0",
      photos: [
        "images/contest/diwali1.jpg",
        "images/contest/diwalc2.jpg",
        "images/contest/145043cd811.png",
        "images/contest/145043def03411.jpg",
        "images/contest/14504ger11.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following code but values in `arrayList_ph` is null. I  am confused about how to parse this JSON content.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int index = 0; index < arr.length(); index++) {

    JSONObject object1 = arr.getJSONObject(index);

    user = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
    user_email = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("email");
    user_profile = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("profile_photo");
    user_count = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("count");
    user_photo_count = arr.getJSONObject(0).getInt("photo_count");
    contest_count = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("contest_count");
    win_count = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("win_count");

    JSONArray ph_arr= arr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("photos");

    for (int in = 0; in < ph_arr.length(); in++) {
        arrayList_ph.add(ph_arr.getString(in));
    }

}
```

Please help me to parse that field.

Comment: you have already asked this type of question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34649000/2553431) so do not repeat same type of question

Comment: In that question issue was not in JSON parsing and that JSON content not same as the above.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution.
This solutions is worked for me.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("");
JSONArray arr = object.optJSONArray("posts");

for (int index = 0; index < arr.length(); index++) {

    JSONObject object1 = arr.optJSONObject(index);

    user = object1.optString("name");
    user_email = object1.optString("email");
    user_profile = object1.optString("profile_photo");
    user_count = object1.optString("count");
    user_photo_count = object1.optInt("photo_count");
    contest_count = object1.optString("contest_count");
    win_count = object1.optString("win_count");

    JSONArray ph_arr = object1.optJSONArray("photos");
    for (int in = 0; in < ph_arr.length(); in++) {
        String str = ph_arr.opt(in).toString();
        arrayList_ph.add(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

 JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("posts”);

     for (int index = 0; index < arr.length(); index++) {
         JSONObject object1 = arr.getJSONObject(index);
         user = object1.getString("name");
         user_email = object1.getString("email");
         user_profile = object1.getString("profile_photo");
         user_count = object1.getInt("count");
         user_photo_count = object1.getInt("photo_count");
         contest_count = object1.getString("contest_count");
         win_count = object1.getString("win_count");

         JSONArray photos_arr= object1.getJSONArray("photos");
              for (int in = 0; in < ph_arr.length(); in++) {
                 String str = ph_arr.get(in).toString();
                 arrayList_ph.add(str);
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your parsing code to this ,

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int index = 0; index < arr.length(); index++) {

    JSONObject object1 = arr.getJSONObject(index);

    user = object1.getString("name");
    user_email = object1.getString("email");
    user_profile = object1.getString("profile_photo");
    user_count = object1.getString("count");
    user_photo_count = object1.getInt("photo_count");
    contest_count = object1.getString("contest_count");
    win_count = object1.getString("win_count");

    JSONArray ph_arr= object1.getJSONArray("photos");

    for (int in = 0; in < ph_arr.length(); in++) {
        String str = ph_arr.get(in).toString();
        arrayList_ph.add(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working on my machine. what is error on your side ? @krishna

Comment: arrayList_ph doesnot contain any value

Comment: arrayList_ph is array you have to make to store values declare it in your class @krishna

Comment: its declared in my class

Comment: i think you are going wrong somewhere in Photos array. @krishna

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check Following:

1) I think your json response is not properly formatted.

**Validate from this:** https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Your json response should be :

```
{  
   "posts":[  
      {  
         "count":1,
         "user_id":"1",
         "name":"Dave Greeneberg",
         "email":"daveneberg@example.com",
         "profile_photo":"http://phontest.lbch.com//users/user1.jpg",
         "contest_count":"3",
         "photo_count":19,
         "win_count":"0",
         "photos":[  
            {  
               "image":"images/contest/diwali1.jpg"
            },
            {  
               "image":"images/contest/diwalc2.jpg"
            },
            {  
               "image":"images/contest/145043cd811.png"
            },
            {  
               "image":"images/contest/145043def03411.jpg"
            },
            {  
               "image":"images/contest/14504ger11.jpg"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

2) If that still does not work...Try debugging and post your log please...